# How to recode multiple columns using for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, recode

I am having problems recoding multiple columns in R.
This is the code I have so far:

```
library(car)
c1 <- sample(1:5, 100, TRUE)
c2 <- sample(1:5, 100, TRUE)
c3 <- sample(1:5, 100, TRUE)
data <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)

col_names <- colnames(data[c(1,3)])
for (name in col_names) {
  data$name <- recode(data$name, "1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2;5=1")
}
```

Everything works until the for-loop. The error says

```
Error: Assigned data `recode(df_meme$name, "1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2;5=1")` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 203 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `name`.
```

I would greatly appreciate an answer! Thank you.

Comment: Try to use `data[[name]]` instead of `data$name` in the `for`-loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `across` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% mutate(across(all_of(col_names), 
                  car::recode, "1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2;5=1"))
```